# user profile ontology

Tags: ontology, user-profile

I work on "consideration of a user profile in information retrieval".
For that I need to implement an ontology of user profile to use this ontology for the improvement of research process.
I do not have much time.
I want to know if it was already done and how? to get an idea?
I am waiting your suggestions and thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

Using a user profile to improve information retrieval is a research field that has at least 20 years worth of history. See, for example, [these papers on Google Scholar](http://scholar.google.co.uk/scholar?hl=en&q=personalized%20information%20retrieval&btnG=&as_sdt=1,5&as_sdtp=) or the research hub for [user modelling](http://www.um.org/). Without a more specific question, it will be impossible to make any more helpful suggestions. In general, the goal of creating a general user profile ontology and the constraint of "I don't have much time" are not compatible. You need to pick a small, manageable specific problem and focus on solving that